# Avoid spawning Reverese words in word search game

Tags: unity, word-games

I was trying to modify a project that I found on Github, but the problem of that game is the words of the game is spawning in reversely as the snapshot below.

[image]

there were two classes that has been used in the script and I couldn't find the issue.
Can someone help me to solve the problem?

**WordSearch Script**

```
public class WordSearch : MonoBehaviour {
    // you may customize these variables in the Unity Inspector however you want
    public bool useWordpool; // 'should we use the wordpool?'
    public TextAsset wordpool; // if true, wordpool will be utilized
    public string[] words; // overwritten if wordpool = true
    public int maxWordCount; // max number of words used
    public int maxWordLetters; // max length of word used 
    public bool allowReverse = false; // if true, words can be selected in reverse order.
    public int gridX, gridY; // grid dimensions
    public float sensitivity; // sensitivity of tiles when clicked
    public float spacing; // spacing between tiles
    public GameObject tile, background, current;             
    public Color defaultTint, mouseoverTint, identifiedTint;
    public bool ready = false, correct = false;
    public string selectedString = "";
    public List<GameObject> selected = new List<GameObject>();

    private List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject temporary, backgroundObject;
    private int identified = 0;
    private float time;
    private string[,] matrix;
    private Dictionary<string, bool> word = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    private Dictionary<string, bool> insertedWords = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    private string[] letters = new string[26]
    {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private int mark = 0;

    private static WordSearch instance;

    public static WordSearch Instance {get {return instance;}}

    void Awake() {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start() {
        List<string> findLength = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;

        if (useWordpool) {
            words = wordpool.text.Split(';');
        } else {
            maxWordCount = words.Length;
        }

        if (maxWordCount <= 0) {
            maxWordCount = 1;
        }

        Mix(words);
        Mathf.Clamp(maxWordLetters, 0, gridY < gridX ? gridX : gridY);

        while (findLength.Count < maxWordCount + 1) {
            if (words[count].Length <= maxWordLetters) {
                findLength.Add(words[count]);
            } 
            count++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maxWordCount; i++) {
            if (!word.ContainsKey(findLength[i].ToUpper()) && !word.ContainsKey(findLength[i])) {
                    word.Add(findLength[i], false);
            }
        }

        Mathf.Clamp01(sensitivity);
        matrix = new string[gridX, gridY];
        InstantiateBG();

        for (int i = 0; i < gridX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridY; j++) {
                temporary = Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(i * 1 * tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing, 10, j * 1 * tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                temporary.name = "tile-" + i.ToString() + "-" + j.ToString();
                temporary.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(180, 0, 0);
                temporary.transform.parent = backgroundObject.transform;
                BoxCollider boxCollider = temporary.GetComponent<BoxCollider>() as BoxCollider;
                boxCollider.size = new Vector3(sensitivity, 1, sensitivity);
                temporary.GetComponent<Letters>().letter.text = "";
                temporary.GetComponent<Letters>().gridX = i;
                temporary.GetComponent<Letters>().gridY = j;
                tiles.Add(tile);
                matrix[i, j] = "";
            }
        }
        CenterBG();
        InsertWords();
        FillRemaining();
        time = Time.time;
    }
    private void CenterBG() {
        backgroundObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, (Screen.height / 2) + 50, 200));
    }

    private void InstantiateBG() {
        if (gridX % 2 != 0 && gridY % 2 == 0) {
            backgroundObject = Instantiate (background, new Vector3 ((tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing)
            * (gridX / 2), 1, (tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing)
            * (gridY / 2) - (tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing)), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        } else if (gridX % 2 == 0 && gridY % 2 != 0) {
            backgroundObject = Instantiate (background, new Vector3 ((tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing) * (gridX / 2)
            - (tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing), 1, (tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing) * (gridY / 2)), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        } else {
            backgroundObject = Instantiate(background, new Vector3 ((tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing) * (gridX / 2) -
                (tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing), 1, (tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing) * (gridY / 2) - (tile.transform.localScale.z * spacing)), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
        backgroundObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(180, 0, 0);
        backgroundObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(((tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing) * gridX), 1, ((tile.transform.localScale.x * spacing) * gridY));
   }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                current = hit.transform.gameObject;
            }
            ready = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                current = hit.transform.gameObject;
            }
            Verify();
        }
    }

    private void Verify() {
        if (!correct) {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> p in insertedWords) {
                if (selectedString.ToLower() == p.Key.Trim().ToLower()) {
                    foreach (GameObject g in selected) {
                        g.GetComponent<Letters>().identified = true;
                    }
                    correct = true;
                }

                if (allowReverse)
                {
                    if (Reverse(selectedString.ToLower()) == p.Key.Trim().ToLower())
                    {
                        foreach (GameObject g in selected)
                        {
                            g.GetComponent<Letters>().identified = true;
                        }
                        correct = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (correct) {
            insertedWords.Remove(selectedString);
            insertedWords.Remove(Reverse(selectedString));

            if (word.ContainsKey (selectedString)) {
                insertedWords.Add (selectedString, true);
            }
            else if (word.ContainsKey(Reverse(selectedString)))
            {
                insertedWords.Add(Reverse(selectedString), true);
            }
            identified++;
        }
        ready = false;
        selected.Clear();
        selectedString = "";
        correct = false;
    }

    private void InsertWords() {
        System.Random rn = new System.Random();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> p in word) {
            string s = p.Key.Trim();
            bool placed = false;
            while (placed == false) {
                int row = rn.Next(gridX);
                int column = rn.Next(gridY);
                int directionX = 0;
                int directionY = 0;
                while (directionX == 0 && directionY == 0) {
                    directionX = rn.Next(3) - 1;
                    directionY = rn.Next(3) - 1;
                }                
                placed = InsertWord(s.ToLower(), row, column, directionX, directionY);
                mark++;
                if (mark > 100) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool InsertWord(string word, int row, int column, int directionX, int directionY) {
        if (directionX > 0) {
            if (row + word.Length >= gridX) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (directionX < 0) {
            if (row - word.Length < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (directionY > 0) {
            if (column + word.Length >= gridY) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (directionY < 0) {
            if (column - word.Length < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (((0 * directionY) + column) == gridY - 1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (matrix [(i * directionX) + row, (i * directionY) + column])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        insertedWords.Add(word, false);
        char[] w = word.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < w.Length; i++) {
            matrix[(i * directionX) + row, (i * directionY) + column] = w[i].ToString();
            GameObject.Find("tile-" + ((i * directionX) + row).ToString() + "-" + ((i * directionY) + column).ToString()).GetComponent<Letters>().letter.text = w[i].ToString();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void FillRemaining() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridY; j++) {
                if (matrix[i, j] == "") {
                    matrix[i, j] = letters[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, letters.Length)];
                    GameObject.Find("tile-" + i.ToString() + "-" + j.ToString()).GetComponent<Letters>().letter.text = matrix[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Mix(string[] words) {
        for (int t = 0; t < words.Length; t++) {
            string tmp = words[t];
            int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(t, words.Length);
            words[t] = words[r];
            words[r] = tmp;
        }
    }

    private string TimeElapsed() {
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.time - time));
        return String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
    }

    private string Reverse(string word)
    {
        string reversed = "";
        char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = letters.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reversed += letters[i];
        }
        return reversed;
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.Label("   Timer: ");
            GUILayout.Label(TimeElapsed());
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> p in insertedWords) {
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.Label("   " + p.Key);
            if (p.Value) {
                GUILayout.Label("*");
            }
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
}
```

**Letters Script**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Letters : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool utilized = false;
    public bool identified = false;
    public TextMesh letter;
    public int gridX, gridY;

    void Start() {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color = WordSearch.Instance.defaultTint;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (WordSearch.Instance.ready) {
            if (!utilized && WordSearch.Instance.current == gameObject) {
                WordSearch.Instance.selected.Add(this.gameObject);
                GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color = WordSearch.Instance.mouseoverTint;
                WordSearch.Instance.selectedString += letter.text;
                utilized = true;
            }
        }

        if (identified) {
            if (GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color != WordSearch.Instance.identifiedTint) {
                GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color = WordSearch.Instance.identifiedTint;
            } 
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            utilized = false;
            if (GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color != WordSearch.Instance.defaultTint) {
                GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].color = WordSearch.Instance.defaultTint;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the question. what i have done is under the Insert method, I changed directionX,directionY

```
while (directionX == 0 && directionY == 0) {
                directionX = rn.Next(3) - 1;
                directionY = rn.Next(3) - 1;
            }
```

to this

```
while (directionX == 0 && directionY == 0) {
                directionX = Mathf.Abs(rn.Next(3) - 1);
                directionY = Mathf.Abs(rn.Next(3) - 1);
            }
```

Which those **directionX,directionY** variables may return minus values when inserting words to the grid.
Thanks.

Comment: You should instead ditch the while loop, and set `directionX = rn.Next(2);` to get either 0 or 1 for x, then `directionY = 1 - directionX;` to get the corresponding value for y in one try, and only one random roll, no absolute values required.

Comment: @DMGregory shouldn't it be `directionY = rn.Next(1 - directionX, 2);` to get the same result then? (Unless there is some other place where diagonal results are discarded that I missed)

Comment: Ah, I didn't observe diagonals in OP's example image, so I'd prematurely assumed they were not valid. In that case it would probably be better to just store an array of valid directions, and select a random index from that array. This avoids both unnecessary guess-and-check looping, and subtle probability distortions that favour horizontal lines over vertical.

Comment: your solutions are also working and thank you both of you!

Comment: @DMGregory do you have any idea of how resetting the puzzle by a button?

Comment: A general strategy would be: after making your puzzle, store a copy of its data in another variable. When the button is pressed, erase the current puzzle state and replace it with your saved copy, as though that were the output of your original generator. If you have trouble implementing this, post it as a new Question.